# AwaitMessages in DMs?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to have an awaitmessage in DMs!

But how its works?

```
     message.channel.awaitMessages( {max: 1, time: 10000})
 .then(async(collected) => {

    if(collected.first().content == 'cancel'){
        message.reply('Command cancelled.')
    }

    console.log('collecred :' + collected.first().content)

}).catch(() => {

message.reply('You took too long! Goodbye!') 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same way as it works in a `TextChannel`,

Also in your options you need to set the property errors and define time as an error.

```js
//msg.author.dmChannel doesn't always exist and if it doesn't it will throw an error 
//so call <User>.createDM() first if you don't know it exists yet
msg.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages({ max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ["time"] })
    .then(async collected => {
    })
    .catch(() => {});
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages